# How to apply the shake effect to a dialog with an embedded form

Tags: jquery-ui, effect, jquery-dialog, shake

I'm newbie on this,  I'm trying to apply the shake effect to a dialog that has an embedded form but not success on this.

When I try to trigger the effect

> $("#restore_password").effect("shake",
>   {times: 3}, 80);

only the fields inside the form tag is taking the effect but the dialog box itself doesn't.

My div

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="restore_password" title="Confirmation code" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" >
           <form> <fieldset> <label for="code">Code</label> <input type="text" name="codecon" id="codecon" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" /> </fieldset> 
           </form> 
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My dialog

```
$("#restore_password").dialog({
                height: 220,
                width: 310,
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                draggable: false,
                resizable: false,
                show: 'puff',
                hiden: 'puff',

                buttons: {

                    "Confirm": function(){

                        $("#change_password").dialog('open');

                    },

                    "Cancel": function(){

                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        $("#forgot_data").dialog('close');
                        $("#dialog-form").dialog('open');
                        setTimeout(function(){
                                $("#name").focus();

                            }, 800);

                    }
                },
                close: function() {
                    allFields.val('').removeClass('ui-state-error');    
                }
            });
```

Any ideas?, it would be helpful.

Comment: For a second, I really thought you were talking about something like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CAM9VFM6HzY

Comment: Does your dialog window survive the effect? For some reason mine is destroyed as effect ends.

Comment: Yep, it is working well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(...).dialog(...);` creates a new element without an id.

e.g.

```
<div id="testingDiv">...</div>
```

becomes

```
<div style="..." class="..." tabindex="..." role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-dialog-title-testingDiv">
    ...
    <div id="testingDiv">...</div>
    ...
</div>
```

So your code is working. What you need to do is target the dialog div e.g.

```
$('div[aria-labelledby=ui-dialog-title-testingDiv]').effect("shake", {times: 3}, 80);
```

Answer (score 3):

Nalum's solution worked, but was a little ugly. Try this one:

```
$('#restore_password').parent().effect("shake", {times: 3}, 80);
```